# List of supported JavaScript events on iPad

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, safari

Is there a list of all supported JavaScript events on the iPad Safari?

Preferably from official Apple pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends which version the operating system is, but [here is a list of supported events](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5) under 'Supported Events'.