# How to capture the hide keyboard event on iOS using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I need to do some resizing of the content of a web page when the hide keyboard button is pressed on an iPad virtual keyboard. Which JavaScript event is launched when the keyboard is hidden?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad Web App: Detect Virtual Keyboard Using JavaScript in Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593139/ipad-web-app-detect-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript-in-safari)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the *focusout* event. It's like blur, but bubbles. It will fire when the keyboard closes  (but also in other cases, of course). In Safari and Chrome the event can only be registered with addEventListener, not with legacy methods. Here is an example I used to restore a Phonegap app after keyboard dismissal.

```
 document.addEventListener('focusout', function(e) {window.scrollTo(0, 0)});
```

Without this snippet, the app container stayed in the up-scrolled position until page refresh.

Comment: Ha, that's the exact scenario I have "restore a Phonegap app after keyboard dismissal"

Comment: This EventListener helped me to fix an issue I had with ExtJS 5; the ExtJS page contents would remain scrolled down for a bit after the IOS keyboard was hidden in Safari. That's a problem since in ExtJS 5.0.1 scrolling is disabled on touch interfaces. Therefore I used this event to trigger a doLayout() on the ExtJS view container which made the container fit again within screen bounds.

Comment: This [often doesn't work on the Chrome 41/iOS 6 emulator on CrossBrowserTesting](http://i.imgur.com/bZbz9Cm.png).

Comment: This works great if there is only one input field, but not if there are multiple. If the user clicks/focuses on a different input field the window will scroll to the top and leave the user wondering what happened to the input field they clicked on.

Comment: @kenecaswell: you could make the scrollTo position dynamic. It doesn't have to always scroll to 0.

Comment: The problem with this is that lots of other things can trigger this, so you'll end up firing your event in other cases when it's not just a keyboard closing...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good place to start [List of supported Javascript events on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885153/list-of-supported-javascript-events-on-ipad)

which leads to https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5

which does not list it.

This one gives a work around [iPad Web App: Detect Virtual Keyboard Using JavaScript in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593139/ipad-web-app-detect-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript-in-safari)

Comment: Thanks, I thins that I will listen to the onblur events. Because when the virtual keyboard is closed, the inputs loose focus.

Comment: @Marius focus is not looses when keyboard hide button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    window.onblur = function(e) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    };
```

This is my solution, which works fine, if someone pressed the "closekeyboard" for iOS 14.7 .